# Is it really important to unit test every component in React app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jestjs

More I am diving into documentation of Jest and Its real world use cases. Lesser I am thinking that writing unit test for every other component is not compulsion. Am I missing on something? can someone please guide me here.

Comment: It's not specific to React or Jest, you may want to learn about automated testing in general and why it's important. Even if you can cut corners on tests, this is something that is learned from experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea is when we are using react to create MVP we tend to write a lot of dynamic code. It is of course impossible to test those for all cases because of some compromised design choices. When testing follow the principle of what you are testing. i.e. You do not want to test if react does it's job of batching and updating states. What you may want to test is if the functions are executed and when they are if they result a proper props. React-testing-library has matured enough to support those. Jest is great for your logic functions i.e. when your are deriving some props of a component from a state. You want the props to be what is in your testing boundary. You don't want to count how many times you jest mocks test or spy run. Just imagine it is a controlled console.log where you mat be looking for certain results. Please do not forget about react and it's batching algorithm. I do not think anybody needs to test react and how it works. Just test your props and your state. If it gets too complex snapshot testing may be the way to go.

Comment: On a similar note please refer to how Dan Abramov brought to light about WET codebase. We all do it but do not want to admit to and react is very friendly with that with cost of testing and validating problems. https://www.deconstructconf.com/2019/dan-abramov-the-wet-codebase